# Static and Dynamic scoping for the given code

Tags: dynamic, scope, static, scoping

I am learning the difference between static and dynamic scoping however I got lost.

```
{
    int x=0;
    void fie(int n){
        x=n+1;
    }
    fie(3)
    write(x);
    {
        int x=0;
        fie(3);
        write(x);
    }
    write(x);
}
```

I can't understand why the code above gives output of 0.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be? It looks a lot like C, but it isn't valid C.

Comment: i guess it's some type of pseudocode... i found it in a book but it does not explain

Comment: Well, without knowing the language, it's impossible to say what the code works in any given way.

Comment: i think it is supposed to be C because the topic is imperative paradigm

Comment: Then the code isn't valid, so if it gives an output of 0, the answer is "Because your compiler is wacky." It might seem like I'm being picky asking about the language, but the thing is, a piece of code only means whatever the language says it means. There aren't any rules to cover this code in any C standard that I know of, so it literally doesn't do anything in standard C.

Comment: can you please explain what is the difference between using static and dynamic then? Thanks